# 12501 Google Sign in Error

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Title says it all. I have an android Project setup with a Google Play Games Sign In Client, and I copied the exact code used in the Google tutorial seen [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples). I have not implemented any `.json` file and any answer from previous threads don't work. Some people say to use a Web ID to authenticate but the sample does not do this. Here is my .java file: https://pastebin.com/Lp1mxV0c

Answer (score 0):

I've got that working by following the [Google Play Games Setup](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) which details the step-by-step instructions you need to perform. It's pretty straightforward.

You need an account in Google Play Store (pay the $25) to be able to experiment with that GPGS Android sample as it involves Achievements, Leaderboards, Events. You also need the AppID of the game from PlayStore to connect to your demo:

```
< string name="app_id">APP_ID FROM PLAYSTORE</string> //from strings.xml
```

Tested on a real-device and I got it working:

[image]

Comment: To clarify, the code sample works, and I have setup the App ID correctly. When I try and setup it in another app with the correct app ID it still does not work and I get the 12501

Comment: how bout package name. did u set it up also? same appID same package name

Comment: Yes I made sure everything it setup in the console correctly my own app still doesn't work

Comment: I should also clarify when I turn the GoogleSignInOptions to DEFAULT_SIGN_IN, the app works but when I switch it do DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN it does not anymore. I have even added my web auth code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by adding the application Id to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
(...)
    <application
    (...)/>
           <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                android:value="@string/app_id"/>
(...)
```